# Is it possible to use pbapply in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have this code where I want to sum the columns of a matrix.

I also want to have a couple of features (my matrix is much bigger than the example below):

- use multiple cores
- have a progress bar

I tried `pbapply` from the pbapply package but without luck. My code is:

```
library(pbapply)
library(parallel)

mat <- matrix(ncol=20, nrow = 50, data = runif(1000))

# sum of the columns
matsum <- apply(mat,2,sum)

# now the same in parallel
cl <- makeCluster(2)
pboptions(type = "txt")
parmat <- pbapply(mat,2,sum, cl=cl)
stopCluster(cl)
```

This leads to the error:

> Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

My question is, is it possible at all to run pbapply in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pbapply` doesn't take the `cl` argument, so no. You can, however, convert your matrix to a data.frame (if that's feasible), and use sapply which should work on columns.

```
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
parmat <- pbsapply(X = mat, FUN = sum, cl = cl)
```

Or, you could try

```
colSums(mat)
```

which is pretty pimped up workhorse.

Answer (score 2):

`pbapply::pbapply` does accept `cl` argument since v 1.3-3 (see [NEWS](https://github.com/psolymos/pbapply/blob/master/NEWS.md))