# Is it possible to get a progress bar with foreach and a "multicore-kind" of backend

Tags: r, progress-bar, parallel-foreach, domc

While using "multicore" parallelism using [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) and the [doMC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html) backend (I use doMC as at the time I looked into it other package did not allow logging from the I would like to get a progress bar, using the [progress](https://github.com/r-lib/progress) package, but any progress (that works on a linux terminal ie no tcltk popups) could do.

Given it uses forking I can imagine it might not be possible but I am not sure.

The intended use is to indicate progress when I load an concatenate 100's of files in parallel (usually within a #!Rscript)

I've looked at the few posts like [How do you create a progress bar when using the “foreach()” function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423760/how-do-you-create-a-progress-bar-when-using-the-foreach-function-in-r). Happy to award a bounty on this.

***EDIT***

500 points bounty offered for someone showing me how to

1. using foreach and a multicore (forking) type of parallelism
2. get a progress bar
3. get logging using futile.logger

**Reprex**

```
# load packages                                                                                                        
library("futile.logger")                                                                                               
library("data.table")                                                                                                  
library("foreach")                                                                                                     
# create temp dir                                                                                                      
tmp_dir <- tempdir()                                                                                                   
# create names for 200 files to be created                                                                             
nb_files <- 200L                                                                                                       
file_names <- file.path(tmp_dir, sprintf("file_%s.txt", 1:nb_files))                                                   
# make it reproducible                                                                                                 
set.seed(1L)                                                                                                           
nb_rows <- 1000L                                                                                                       
nb_columns <- 10L                                                                                                      
# create those 200 files sequentially                                                                                  
foreach(file_i = file_names) %do%                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                      
    DT <- as.data.table(matrix(data = runif(n = nb_rows * nb_columns), nrow = nb_rows))                                
    fwrite(x = DT, file = file_i)                                                                                      
    flog.info("Creating file %s", file_i)                                                                              
} -> tmp                                                                                                               

# Load back the files                                                                                                  
foreach(file_i = file_names, .final = rbindlist) %dopar%                                                               
{                                                                                                                      
    flog.info("Loading file %s", file_i)                                                                               
    # >>> SOME PROGRESS BAR HERE <<<                                                                                   
    fread(file_i)                                                                                                      
} -> final_data                                                                                                        
# show data                                                                                                            
final_data
```

**Desired output**

Note that the progress bar **is not** messed up with the print lines)

```
INFO [2018-07-18 19:03:48] Loading file /tmp/RtmpB13Tko/file_197.txt
INFO [2018-07-18 19:03:48] Loading file /tmp/RtmpB13Tko/file_198.txt
INFO [2018-07-18 19:03:48] Loading file /tmp/RtmpB13Tko/file_199.txt
INFO [2018-07-18 19:03:48] Loading file /tmp/RtmpB13Tko/file_200.txt
[ =======>                          ] 4%
```

***EDIT 2***

After the bounty ended nothing comes close to the expected result.

Logging within the progress bar messes everything.
If someone gets the correct result I'll give another result-based bounty.

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222236/do-parallel-combine-progress-bar-and-process, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199631/parsapply-and-progress-bar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450470/is-it-possible-to-use-pbapply-in-parallel

Comment: Can you please add example how you specify parallel process (using `doMC`).

Comment: Or even better - can you give an actual code snippet that you want to run/parallelize with progress bar?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution (not perfect) using custom function.

This function outputs to console (using `message`) progress bar.

- `ii` is current iteration.
- `N` is total number of iterations to perform.
- `per` is step (percent) when to update the progress bar. We need this as when multiple iterations are being performed progress bar gets updated too often and output is messed up.

Function:

```
progBar <- function(ii, N, per = 10) {
    if (ii %in% seq(1, N, per)) {
        x <- round(ii * 100 / N)
        message("[ ", 
                paste(rep("=", x), collapse = ""),
                paste(rep("-", 100 - x), collapse = ""), 
                " ] ", x, "%", "\r",
                appendLF = FALSE)
        if (ii == N) cat("\r")
    }
}
```

Code to test:

```
library(doMC)
library(foreach)
registerDoMC(10)

nIteration <- 1e3
foreach(i = 1:nIteration, ii = icount()) %dopar% {
    # For progBar ii I'm using icount(), because
    # user might iterate over all kind of objects
    progBar(ii, nIteration)
    Sys.sleep(1 / 10)
}
```

[image]

PS: It's not perfect, because:

- Bar not always runs to `100%` (depending on the number of iterations it can stop at `99%`)
- Sometimes output messes up (depends on number of iterations and how often they switch) - still debugging this part
- Console is not flushed if you use `print`/`cat` within `foreach`

Comment: Is it possible if I use doParallel instead of doMC

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this link [Progress bar parallel](https://github.com/r-lib/progress/issues/39) for the few insights (May be not the exact solution) which will help in creating a progress bar parallel.

The `txtProgressBar` only works when the stype is 2 or 3

```
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")
library("progress")

registerDoParallel(parallel::makeCluster(7, outfile = ""))

pb <- progress_bar$new(
            format = " [:bar] :percent in :elapsed",
            total = 30, clear = FALSE, width = 80, force = T)
a <- foreach (i  = 1:30) %dopar% {
    pb$tick()
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
}


pb <- txtProgressBar(title = "Iterative training", min = 0, max = 30, style = 3)

foreach (i  = 1:30) %dopar% {
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Do refer this link [Monitoring the function with progress bar](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/) for the different ways a progress bar can be implemented depending on the needs.

**Using Multicore:**
You can register a different parallel backend later, or deregister doMC by registering the sequential backend by calling the registerDoSEQ function. For example consider the following program

```
> x <- iris[which(iris[,5] != "setosa"), c(1,5)]
> trials <- 10000
> ptime <- system.time({
+ r <- foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
+ ind <- sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)
+ result1 <- glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1], family=binomial(logit))
+ coefficients(result1)
+ }
+ })[3]
> ptime
```

Comment: This is not using multicore parallelism is it?

Comment: @statquant.. I have updated the above answer  with a small example on multicore

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows 10, R 3.6.1, my bet is that it's an OS problem. The progress bar won't progress, not even with flush.console()

Answer (score -1):

A package I have used that does this in parallel for processing lists is `pbmcapply`, hope this helps.

Comment: well I 'd like to keep the foreach syntax that I like. Is that a multicore type of parallelism?

Comment: It is multicore, it operates the same way using lapply does, but in addition you can specify the number of cores you'd like to use. I found it to be most beneficial when wanting to parallelize a function over an object / list of dataframes, works similar to map, but in parallel. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbmcapply/index.html

Comment: OK so it means it should be doable with foreach then